# to know ip docker-machine on runner GitLab CI

Tags: postgresql, docker, gitlab-ci-runner

I want to write yml script for GitLabCI with runing docker with postgres. The docker start is OK, I can see docker with command:

```
docker container ls

PORTS                    NAMES
0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp   postgres
```

How to know ip adress docker machine to create a url for database?
The command

```
docker-machine ls

bash: line 71: docker-machine: command not found
```

Also I tried to connect by the:

```
jdbc:postgresql://0.0.0.0:5432/psg
jdbc:postgresql://containerName:5432/psg
jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/psg
jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/psg
```

Its not working too.

Answer (score 1):

`docker inspect --format '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' postgres` could get the container ip address.